# How to pass MongoDB _id inside of get request to retrieve a collection

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, get, request

Building an app on Vue, Express, Mongo and Node. Trying to use _id from a mongo record to retrieve that records contents. I can use postman with the exact path /builds/5a9e3870b73d8f342ea7da56 and it returns what I need. But I want the user to be able to input an _id into a textbox and the get request will use that to get the record.

```
app.get('/builds/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log("query params:", req.query);
  model.Build.find({_id: req.params.id }).then(function(build) {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.json(build);
  });
});
```

Basically what I am asking is what can I add on my html side so that whatever id the user enters into a text box gets sent as a get request.

Comment: use Axios package

Comment: Just do an ajax GET request to /builds/:id passing your id as the data